# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server from a C program

Tags: sql, c, sql-server, connection, sql-server-express

I set Microsoft SQL Server using SQL Express on one laptop.

1. I created a test database with test table.
2. I created login in Security/Logins with login name = my_uuid and I marked "SQL Server authentication"
3. I created a user in Databases/my_db/Security/Users, I named it my_uuid and I set its login name to my_uuid (the one I created before). Then I granted it all the permissions.
4. In Sql Server Configuration Manager/SQL Server Configuration/Protocols for SQLEXPRESS i set TCP/IP to Enabled, in TCP/IP properties I found that IP4 has the IP assigned to the WIFI network (10.3.200.221), so I set IP4 Enabled to 'Yes'. Also I set port to 50100.

Now in the other laptop I am trying to access to this database with my test C program.
I noticed that below function always returns -1:

```
SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle, NULL, "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.3.200.221:50100;DATABASE = my_db;UID = my_uuid;PWD = my_pwd;", SQL_NTS,
                                  retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

I believe that third parameter(InConnectionString) is invalid. I tried many examples found on the internet and I am still stuck. I can also mention that I can ping to this laptop with no problems.

Comment: Verify remote connectivity with PowerShell command `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 10.3.200.221 -Port 50100`. If that fails, view the SQL Server error log to see the IP and port SQL Server is actually listening on. Note that you may need to restart the SQL Server service if the WIFI interface didn't yet have an IP when the SQL Server service started.  Also, TCP port 50100 needs to be allowed through the firewall.

Comment: If you actually changed the SQL Server configuration you need to restart the SQL Server service for the changes to be applied. Also, depending on the actual driver being used, you may need to use `SERVER=10.3.200.221,50100;` (note the comma instead of a colon).

Comment: _below function always returns -1:_ For writing to the ODBC API you need to get the actual error information when an error occurs - which is another function call.

Comment: Thanks, Now it works. I indeed had problems with connection to port 50100, setting the port number in IPALL option in TCP/IP properties solved this problem. The other problem was colon instead of comma. The only issue I have now is the time it takes to connect to the database. It takes abut 10 seconds, but generally speaking my main problem is solved.